# Swift: Create a custom UITableviewCell without defining IBOutlet vars

Tags: uitableview

I want to create a custom `UITableviewCell` subclass with RTL `UItextlabel` text alignment by default. I wrote this small code for that:

```
class rtlCell : UITableViewCell {
    override var textLabel: UILabel {
       let label = UILabel()
       label.textAlignment = .right
       return label
    }
}
```

but this text label doesn't show up in the cell. I know it can be done by defining an `IBOutlet` label var and connecting a label to it in the storyboard, but I wonder if there is a way to do so without doing these things?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new label and not adding it to the View hierarchy, your code would work if just styled super.textLabel, e.g. like this:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell
{
    override var textLabel: UILabel? {
        let label = super.textLabel
        label?.textAlignment = .right
        return label
    }
}
```

But I think you should move your UI customisation code to some other place (e.g. tableView delegate)